# File Upload to Dropbox from FORM with PHP

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I am so close.  I am trying to create a form that will upload a file to my Dropbox, and I can get it to work using a file on the server with the code here:

```
$path = 'render.png';
$fp = fopen($path, 'rb');
ch = curl_init('https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

I was sure this would work, but nope.....

```
$fp = fopen($_FILES['file'], 'rb');
```

Anyone have a quick fix for this?

Comment: Did you authorise?

Comment: Yes I have other code with the headers.  The code at the top works, it will upload the 'render.png' file.  The problem is getting the file from the form $_FILES['file'] to work.  I get an empty file on the server.

Comment: What is the name of the input for the file in your HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem

```
$fp = fopen($_FILES['file'], 'rb');
```

You will need to use the `tmp_name` field from $_FILES as that is the location of the temporary file that PHP places in the temp folder.

```
$fp = fopen($_FILES['fred']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
```

Where `'fred'` is the value of the `name` attribute in

```
<input type="file" name="fred".....`
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was missing something really simple.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Flysystem. I'm using it with Laravel but I believe it also works as a standalone.

http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/